# Azure functions

Tags: azure, websocket, azure-functions

We need to import data from a service provider that only supports getting data through web sockets. We would like to it from Azure Function, but I is that even possible to create a connection in an azure function app?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Functions is just a way of running code snippets in a serverless environment. You can write your function in a multitude of languages, including C# and Python. So anything you can do in those languages, you can whack into an Azure Function.

For example, there is a Python package called `websockets` you could use.